# О вопросительном знаке

Tags: пунктуация

Прочитала предыдущий вопрос о "крестце" и у меня возник свой. А именно: нужен ли вопросительный знак в предложениях типа "Как пройти в библиотеку, подскажите, пожалуйста"?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ларf права - вопросительного знака не нужно, местоименное наречие КАК считается относительным, а не вопросительным, оно присоединяет придаточное предложение к главному.

Но желательно поставить тире для обозначения смысловой паузы при инверсии придаточного изъяснительного:  Как пройти в библиотеку - подскажите, пожалуйста. В этом случае первая фраза произносится с повышением тона, что имитирует вопросительную интонацию. Именно для этого и делается инверсия.

Похожие примеры:Он приедет, но когда – не знаю. Хорошо, что они венчаются, а как жить будут – кто знает. Как рассказывал учитель – долго слушал у окна я.

Answer (score 4):

Вопросительный знак не нужен, так как предложение по цели высказывания побудительное(подскажите), относительное местоименное наречие "как" присоединяет придаточное к главному. Если вы хотите подчеркнуть вопросительную интонацию, тогда можно оформить по-другому: Подскажите, пожалуйста: как пройти в библиотеку?